# geom_smooth method="rlm" object 'rlm' of mode 'function' was not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y))+
 geom_point(na.rm=T)+
 geom_smooth(method="rlm", se=T)
```

error message: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: object 'rlm' of mode 'function' was not found

Do I need to download any package for rlm? why do I get this message

Comment: If `rlm` is a function from a package then, yes, you need to load the package prior to using the function.

Answer (score 4):

You've already downloaded the package (automatically when you installed ggplot). You just need to load it with `library(MASS)`.

A few ways to find functions in packages:

- `help("rlm", try.all.packages = T)` is a great way to find function in installed packages. No internet access needed!
- Searching for "ggplot rlm" does a pretty good job with in a search engine. My first hit was an example that had the `library(MASS)` line.
- You can search for functions on https://www.rdocumentation.org/. There's actually a package called `rlm` (that *might* work with ggplot, I'm not sure), but since you're using `ggplot` you need only look at packages that are in the `Imports` or `Suggests` fields in the ggplot2 description ([CRAN link](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ggplot2))

Of course, it would be nice if there was a helpful message or this was mentioned in the `geom_smooth` documentation. Or if it wasn't necessary at all.